# How to scale smaller values more

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, rotation, vector

Hello it seems like it should be easy and i am missing something but i really couldn't find a solution as i am fairly new to programming.
So basically i want to rotate a object faster when its closer to another object. My code is below and i want the rotationSpeed to be a higher value when its closer.

```
rotationSpeed = Mathf.Sqrt(
        Mathf.Pow(sphere.center.X - playerSphere.center.X, 2)
        + Mathf.Pow(sphere.center.Y - playerSphere.center.Y, 2)
        + Mathf.Pow(sphere.center.Z - playerSphere.center.Z, 2));
```

eg: 10 * x = 50,
    5  * x = 100

Comment: Your current code can be written much more concisely as `rotationSpeed = (playerSphere.center - sphere.center).magnitude;`

Comment: Is there a particular rule for how we should pick the speed number? Does this scaling correspond to any specific real-world phenomenon, like winding a cable around a spool, or a satellite orbiting a planet? Or does it need to meet any specific gameplay metrics/constraints like "rotation speed should never exceed 100, distance between spheres should never be outside (5...50)..." etc?

Comment: I am trying to create a tornado in my 2D lunar lander game. So the idea is the closer you are to the tornado the character rotates faster and pulls the character inside faster. As i didn't test the result i don't know if i will need a constrain but if i get the idea i assume i can achieve that with clamping. Also i am using my own Vector class to learn the fundamentals but maybe its a good idea to make a Magnitude function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
rotationSpeed = aConstant / Vector3.Distance(sphere.position, playerSphere.position)
```

So basically the idea here is that you have a float constant and you're dividing it by distance. So when they're close to each other, the rotation speed will be higher. You can also limit it with an if statement or take the square root of the distance to make it smaller. Just make sure that the distance is never being 0, the division may throw an exception.

P.S. `Vector3.Distance(a,b)` is the same as `(a-b).magnitude`